# Firebase updating collection/storage regenerates the same file in the storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to link my images into the collection with getDownloadUrl.I have 3 methods on the admin page add/delete/edit. Add and delete work properly but when I want to edit an existing item firebase regenerates the same image multiple times, as you can see in the image. I attached the codeSandbox link to the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-feather-uydu8v?file=/src/delete.js).

In the end, I am getting the right link to the image for my collection doc and properly updating the existing image.

[image]

Comment: Updating should replace the existing file as long as you are providing the same StorageReference. Please edit your question and add the code that is not working as intended (apart from the Sandbox) or at least point towards to code updating the file.

Comment: So when I want to update the existing file (not collection) with a new file shouldn't I delete the existing storage file first and .then upload the new file so I can .getDownloadURL for the new file and use it as a new link in the collection by .setDoc?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, please focus on the Edit file because I only share add and delete files to show that the program is running in add/delete file correctly.